# Changing name of app in PlayStore

Tags: android, rename, google-play

I had an app in the PlayStore named "**abc def**", and it could be found when searching for "**abc def**".

Now I unpublished this app, and it cannot be found anymore - so far, so good.

Now I uploaded a new app named "**abc_def**" (the same name as above, but with an underline), and it can be found when searching for "**abc_def**".

BUT now I changed the name of the new app to "**abc def**", and I cannot find it when searching for "**abc def**", only when searching for "**abc_def**", even though the name of the app is already updated in the PlayStore (not only in the Developer Console).

Does it take Google some time to refresh the search index, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: even the "refresh" needs much time by google. Don´t fear it, it will be changed soon...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of app both places: Google Play Developer Console and in the application itself before compiling to apk and re-upload to Google Play. Have you done that already?

Comment: The app name in the AndroidManifest hasn't been changed, only the name in the Console.

Comment: I believe Google Play pulls app info such as logo/icon and name from Manifest. I had to change name in AndroidManifest too when I changed name of my app.

Comment: @deimos1988 did my response help? did you change app name in AndroidManifest too?